# Fire rule when Enter Key is pressed. Adobe DTM

Tags: forms, keypress, adobe-dtm

I have this code in my Custom code section of an event based rule in DTM. I am trying to fire the rule upon the Enter key press. The input is not within a form element. How to I get the Keycode scoped into my custom page code? Any help would be appreciated!

```
jQuery(this).keypress(function (e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var frmData = 'search:new:submit';
    var inpData = jQuery(this).siblings('input').val().trim().toLowerCase();
    _satellite.setVar('frmData', frmData);
    _satellite.setVar('inpData', inpData);
    return true;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to fire by switching the event type to Keypress and using this simple code. -cheers

```
if (event.keyCode == 13){ 
   return true;
}
```